MAUI app crashes while not debugging, InvalidCastException for TextColor
I made a MAUI app which I can run and debug in the emulator but whenever I run it without debugging (in either the emulator or on a physical device) it crashes while opening some pages. I enabled reporting all exceptions in Visual Studio and now while debugging I get lots of strange errors one of which being an InvalidCastException. It seems, the framework is somehow trying to interpret some TextColor values in XAML and fails on that.
On the page where this exception gets thrown I deleted all the TextColor value assignments and unfortunately I still get the exception.
If anyone knows a solution to this, I'll appreciate.

{System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TextElement.OnTextColorPropertyChanged(BindableObject
bindable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\TextElement.cs:line 24    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueActual(BindableProperty
property, BindablePropertyContext context, Object value, Boolean
currentlyApplying, SetValueFlags attributes, SetterSpecificity
specificity, Boolean silent) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindableObject.cs:line 643    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueCore(BindableProperty
property, Object value, SetValueFlags attributes, SetValuePrivateFlags
privateAttributes, SetterSpecificity specificity) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindableObject.cs:line 569    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValue(BindableProperty
property, Object value, SetterSpecificity specificity) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindableObject.cs:line 503    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Setter.Apply(BindableObject target,
SetterSpecificity specificity) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Setter.cs:line 81    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Style.ApplyCore(BindableObject bindable, Style
basedOn, SetterSpecificity specificity) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Style.cs:line 176    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Style.Microsoft.Maui.Controls.IStyle.Apply(BindableObject
bindable, SetterSpecificity specificity) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Style.cs:line 107    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.MergedStyle.SetStyle(IStyle implicitStyle,
IList`1 classStyles, IStyle style) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\MergedStyle.cs:line 211    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.MergedStyle.set_Style(IStyle value) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\MergedStyle.cs:line 46    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NavigableElement.<>c.<.cctor>b__22_0(BindableObject
bindable, Object oldvalue, Object newvalue) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Shell\NavigableElement.cs:line 21
at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueActual(BindableProperty
property, BindablePropertyContext context, Object value, Boolean
currentlyApplying, SetValueFlags attributes, SetterSpecificity
specificity, Boolean silent) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindableObject.cs:line 643    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueCore(BindableProperty
property, Object value, SetValueFlags attributes, SetValuePrivateFlags
privateAttributes, SetterSpecificity specificity) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindableObject.cs:line 569    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValue(BindableProperty
property, Object value) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindableObject.cs:line 474    at
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.TrySetValue(Object
element, BindableProperty property, Boolean attached, Object value,
IXmlLineInfo lineInfo, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Exception&
exception) in
D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:line
631}



In line 24 of your TextElement.cs class, you are trying to do an invalid cast.  Without showing any of your code, this is the best answer you are going to get.

TextElement.cs is not my class. It seems to be part of the MAUI framework (Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueActual()).

Can you see the values that are being converted in the debugger?

So, the solution was to enable catching all exceptions in VS (Debug > Windows > Exception Settings Ctrl+Alt+E). Then I was able to catch the InvalidCastException. Then I found the simplest XAML page in my app where this exception was thrown (apparently, it's thrown by the XAML interpreter so I can't just debug it in classic step-by-step manner). Then I erased all the content in that page (remember to make a backup) and then I started to add in all the components one by one and restarting the app until I saw where the error started.
Turns out, I had a Button which had a style applied to it (Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButton}") and the style's definition was in the App.xaml file.
<Style x:Key="PrimaryButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#e6eaed"/>
</Style>

The definition contained a Setter for the TextColor property and a Value for it. For some reason the XAML interpreter had a problem with it. After deleting the line with the Setter the error disappeared and the app started to work correctly. And the TextColor is inherited from some other object so it's still the same as I need it (lucky me).
